# How to find directory combination

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

Within a dir, I am trying to find anything that matches config/db, where db could be a file or dir.

I tried:

```
find /search/root/dir -wholename 'config/common'
```

but that didn't work - result set was empty but I know that path exists, anybody know how to find a path with slashes in it?

Comment: Why not call find in /search/root/dir/config?

Comment: Try `find /search/root/dir -wholename '*/config/db'`

Comment: Thanks Mark, it looks like that worked, feel free to add as answer will select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know only the partial path then -wholename, may not work.

You can use..

```
 find . -path "/search/root/dir/config/*" 
 find . -path "*/search/root/dir/config/"
```